# how to make executable executing within one specific directory only (executable source code available)

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, executable, program-entry-point

how to prevent tool (executable) executing from any other directories except specified one? May edit tool source code and recompile it. Linux-based OS.

Answer (score 0):

Call `getcwd()` and check whether the directory is the specified directory.

```
#define ALLOWED_DIR "/foo/bar/baz"
char dir[BUFSIZ];
getcwd(dir, BUFSIZ);
if (strcmp(dir, ALLOWED_DIR) != 0) {
  /* complain and exit */
}
```

EDIT

From your comments, it appears that you aren't looking for the directory that the user is executing from, but the directory containing the executable itself. There's no completely reliable way to do this, see http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-do-i-get-the-application-path-in-c-426517/

Checking the executable location does't provide any real security. If someone makes a copy of the program, they can simply remove the part that checks where it is.

If you want to ensure that users only use the official, installed version of a program, you need to make it depend on accessing something that ordinary users cannot access. Then make the program setuid or setgid, so that it can access it. Then it won't work if they try to run their copy, because it won't run with the appropriate permissions.

Comment: is `getcwd()` libc c/c++ function? the source code is written in c

Comment: getcwd - get the pathname of the current working directory. is "current working directory" exactly the same as executable path? it seems that it can be passed as invocation parameter and can differ

Comment: It's the directory the user is in via the `cd` command. Why do you care where the executable is located?

Comment: Well, then it's not what i'm looking for (Thanks for the link BTW). It's security issue. I know that is can/should be solved in another way, but the question is exactly as i ask.

Comment: See my updated answer regarding using setuid/setgid to implement this kind of security.